# IE8: First event works, second one doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, datatables

The following code, to edit a cell of a [Datatable](http://datatables.net/), seems to work in FF and Chrome, but only works once in IE8....i.e. there are no subsequent click events

JQuery: 1.8 Datatables: 1.10 (this code was written prior to 1.10)

```js
var self = this;
// Setup edit listener
dataTable.on('click.insight.autotable', 'td', function (event) {
  if (self._isCellEditable(this)) {
    // If not already selected cell
    if (self._currentCell !== this) {
      if (self._currentCell !== null) {
        self.saveAndClose();
      }
      self.switchToEditMode(this);
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

This has been crossposted to the datatables forum, but response seems a little limited. I think it is a JQuery issue instead of a Datatable  issue, but any solution proving me wrong will still be appreciated :-)

**Update**: Unfortunately I can't post the entire code, but [this example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html) seems to demonstrate similar behaviour in IE8, where it only generates one event in comparison to a list of events in other browsers.